# Dynamically import modules

Tags: python, import, loader

Client want a script(here `main.py`) with configurable partner modules,
so in future he can add a new `partner_x.py` with few custom changes if required and push it to production without any help of a developer. 
therefore we wrote a script with this directory structure:

Project directory structure:

```
├── partners
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── partner_1.py
│   ├── partner_2.py
│   ├── ...
│   └── partner_n.py
├── main.py
```

**Problem statement**:
He runs a cron script to identify the email coming from the partner to get the partner name and runs our script using a Cronjob.

```
partner_cron.py
    #Downloads Gmail Attachment and decide partner
    partner = decide_partner_from_gmail()
    python ~/project/main.py partner
```

But in our main script (i.e. `main.py`), we imported all the partner modules even though at a time it processes data for one partner.

I am trying to optimize my below lines of `main.py`:

```
if sys.argv[1] == "partner_1"
   from partners import partner_1 as partner

if sys.argv[1] == "partner_2"
   from partners import partner_2 as partner
.
.
.
if sys.argv[1] == "partner_n"
   from partners import partner_n as partner
```

In the future, client could have at least 20-30 `partners`, so it would not be a good way of writing 20-30 `if-else` to import specific partner.

I believe there should be some good approach to import a module dynamically instead of one by one.

1. Can we import only one partner module by using any kind of [Configuration files in Python](https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/) OR
2. Is there any other way to import such modules dynamically?
3. OR Is there any other way to do this better way?

I'm looking for this kind of import statement:

```
from partners import  module( sys.argv[1] )
```

Comment: Look at the built-in function `__import__()`.  It's a bit messy to use directly, but it's the function used implicitly by any ``import`` line in the source code.